Create Webhook subscription
I'm currently trying to set up a webhook subscription with the ServiceM8 API, but I'm running into an error. Here's the cURL command I'm using:
curl --location '<https://api.servicem8.com/webhook_subscriptions'>
--header 'authorization: Bearer Access Token'
--form 'object="job"'
--form 'fields="status"'
--form 'callback_url="Our webhook URL"'>

we have added the challenge part to our request, but we are encountering the following error:
{
"success": false,
"message": "Invalid callback challenge key returned",
"detail": "Expected 'a8a147bf6182d074' but received ''"
}

Below is our .NET C# code:
Method 1: C#
[HttpPost]
[Route("handlewebhook")]
public IActionResult HandleWebhook()
{
    var mode = Request.Form["mode"].ToString();
    var challenge = Request.Form["challenge"].ToString();

    Console.WriteLine($"Received Mode: {mode}, Challenge: {challenge}");

    if (mode == "subscribe" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(challenge))
    {
        // Respond to verification request with the challenge value
        return Ok(challenge);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var jsonData = JObject.Parse(body);

            var entry = jsonData["entry"]?.First;
            if (entry != null)
            {
                var changedFields = entry["changed_fields"];
                var time = entry["time"]?.ToString();
                var uuid = entry["uuid"]?.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine($"Changed Fields: {changedFields}, Time: {time}, UUID: {uuid}");
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}

Method 2: C#
[HttpPost]
[Route("handlewebhook")]
public IActionResult HandleWebhook([FromForm] string mode, [FromForm] string challenge)
{
    if (mode == "subscribe" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(challenge))
    {
        // Respond to verification request
        return Ok(challenge);
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle webhook POST data
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var jsonData = JObject.Parse(body);

            // Extract data from the JSON
            var entry = jsonData["entry"]?.First;
            if (entry != null)
            {
                var changedFields = entry["changed_fields"];
                var time = entry["time"]?.ToString();
                var uuid = entry["uuid"]?.ToString();

                // Process the data as needed
                Console.WriteLine($"Changed Fields: {changedFields}, Time: {time}, UUID: {uuid}");
            }

            return Ok(); // Respond with 200 OK for webhook data
        }
    }
}

Please let us know how we can resolve this issue. Thank you for your assistance!
We are trying to update the job status using our webhook URL. How can we subscribe to the webhook URL, and how can we fix the error below?
{
"success": false,
"message": "Invalid callback challenge key returned",
"detail": "Expected 'a8a147bf6182d074' but received ''"
}

